# Classes and files manipulation in C++

Tags: c++, function, class, file-io

I wrote a code that works fine. I just want extra eyes to highlight every thing that should/could be improved. I have to create a student.dat file, and write data (name, age, gpa of each student) given by a user, then close it, and reopen it for reading then, displaying the gpa of students. The Student is a Class object. I just want to check where I am with the notion of OOP (at least with that problem). I am using Dev-C++. The code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

#define W setw
using namespace std;

class Student
{
private:
    char name[40];
    int age;
    double GPA;

public:
    Student(){};
    void read();
    void show(char* ,int ,double ); 
    int writefile(ofstream &OS);
    double getgpa(double*, int );
    void readfile();
};



void Student::read(void)
{
int nbrSt=0;
cout<<"Please enter the information of the student: "<<endl;
cout<<"'y' to Continue, Ctrl+Z to exit! "<<endl;    
cout<<"Name, Age and GPA:\n";


ofstream OS("student.dat", ios::out);
while (cin>>name>>age>>GPA)
{       
        //writing in the file
        writefile(OS);
        nbrSt++;  //increment the number of students
        cout<<"Name, Age and GPA:\n";
}
OS.close();

}

int Student::writefile(ofstream & OS)
{

OS<<'\n'<<W(10)<<name<<W(6)<<age<<W(10)<<GPA;

 return 0;   
}

void Student::show(char* Name, int Age, double gpa)
 {
cout<<'\n'<<W(10)<<Name<<W(6)<<Age<<W(8)<<gpa<<endl;    

 }

double Student::getgpa(double* allGPA, int nbrgpa)
{
double sum=0;
int i =0;

 for ( i=0;i<nbrgpa; i++)
   sum+=allGPA[i];

 if(nbrgpa>0)
   return sum/nbrgpa;

 }


void Student::readfile()
{
char Name[30];
int Age;
double aveGPA, gpa;
    int nbrgpa=0;
double  allGPA[50];
int i=0;


ifstream IS("Student.dat", ios::in);
cout<<"reading from Binary file"<<endl;

if (IS.is_open())

    while(IS>>Name>>Age>>gpa)
    {   
        nbrgpa++;
        show(Name, Age, gpa);
        allGPA[i]=gpa;
        i++;    
}
  IS.close();


aveGPA=getgpa( allGPA, nbrgpa);

cout<<"Average GPA of students: "<<aveGPA<<endl;

}

int main(void)
{
Student S;

S.read();
S.readfile();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Indenting it properly would be a big improvement. Using readable names instead of e.g. `W` and `nbrgpa` might also be a good idea, if you want other people (or yourself after a few days) to read it.

Comment: You're using `Student` more as a namespace than an object. So: there's only the slightest hint of "OOP" in your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
Student(){};
```

is illegal syntax

```
Student(){}
```

is correct.

---

```
void Student::read(void)
```

is badly designed. Student::read should be a method which reads one student. The reading of multiple stduents and the writing of students should be in other functions or methods.

---

```
int Student::writefile(ofstream & OS)
```

should be

```
int Student::writefile(ostream & OS)
```

so it works with all kinds of streams (not just file streams). Obviously you should then rename the method. Just call it write for instance.

---

```
double Student::getgpa(double* allGPA, int nbrgpa)
```

should not be a member of Student, it should be a global function.

---

Your main issue is object-orientated design. You shouldn't just add everything to the `Student` class without thinking about what you are doing. Methods in the Student class should be about one student, methods that read or write one Student for instance. Everything else should be in global functions (or in other classes if you add a second class to your program).

Comment: Writefile is required by the assignment, so it will work for filestream (only). getgpa is also required to be a member function. All I did, was to figure out the arguments of each function, as they were not provided.

Comment: @john why getgpa() should not be a member of Student? it accepts all the gpa and then extracts the particualr student i guess. do you mean to say that student be an explicit parameter and then work on it?

Comment: `Student(){};` is _not_ illegal syntax.  A function definition in a class can be followed by an optional `'`.  (C++11 has extended this to allow an empty statement, and thus an extra `;` after or between statements, everywhere.)

Comment: I tried either way, and the compiler did not return any error. I guess I am using C++11.

Comment: A student is a name, age and GPA. getgpa() does not do anything with those. It averages GPA's passed in an array.

Answer (score 1):

> I just want extra eyes to highlight every thing that should/could be improved.

```
#define W setw
```

Don't do that. You may think it makes code using setw look simpler, but other people looking at your code will have to search for what W resolves to.

```
using namespace std;
```

Don't declare using namespace std globally. It's not a big problem in small projects, but it makes the code more difficult to reuse.

The interface of your class is non-standard. Consider reading by creating `ostream << student` operator and reading by creating 'istream >> student'. This respects the rule of least surprise and enables you to (for example) read a sequence of students using iteration.

You need much better function names:

Your read function writes to a file. It would be a big WTF moment for me to see that in production code. Either change the name, or change the functionality.

Your read function is called on a student instance (`Student s; s.read();`) but it doesn't work on an instance. It in fact transfers/stores a set of records from `cin` to a file, and sets the instance it is called on, to the last record. If the reading fails half way through the data (i.e. `cin>>name>>age>>GPA` gets the name correctly but not the age or GPA) it leaves the instance it is called on, in an invalid state.

Consider moving your code from `char name[40];` and `double* allGPA, int nbrgpa` to `std::string` and `std::vector<double>` respectively. Using raw data is error-prone and unnecessarily complicated.

There's a lot more to be said, but I think I've given you enough :-).

Comment: Thanks utnapistim, I will work on all those remarks and suggestions.